# bytes object has no attribute find_all

Tags: web-scraping, byte, python-requests, beautifulsoup

I've been trying for the last 3 hours to scrape this [website](https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/esports/standings) and get the rank, name, wins, and losses of each team.

When implementing this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

halo = requests.get("https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/esports/standings")

page = BeautifulSoup(halo.content, "html.parser")

final = page.encode('utf-8')

print(final.find_all("div"))
```

I keep getting this [error](http://prntscr.com/bq9dyl)

If anyone can help me out then it would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the the method on the wrong variable, use the BeautifulSoup object *page* **not** the byte string *final*:

```
print(page.find_all("div"))
```

To get the table data is pretty straightforward, all the data is inside the div with the css classes *"table.table--hcs"*:

```
halo = requests.get("https://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/esports/standings")

page = BeautifulSoup(halo.content, "html.parser")


table = page.select_one("div.table.table--hcs")
print(",".join([td.text for td in table.select("header div.td")]))
for row in table.select("div.tr"):
    rank,team = row.select_one("span.numeric--medium.hcs-trend-neutral").text,row.select_one("div.td.hcs-title").span.a.text
    wins, losses = [div.span.text for div in row.select("div.td.em-7")]
    print(rank,team, wins, losses)
```

If we run the code, you can see the data matches the table:

```
In [4]: print(",".join([td.text for td in table.select("header div.td")]))
Rank,Team,Wins,Losses

In [5]: for row in table.select("div.tr"):
   ...:         rank,team = row.select_one("span.numeric--medium.hcs-trend-neutral").text,row.select_one("div.td.hcs-title").span.a.text
   ...:         wins, losses = [div.span.text for div in row.select("div.td.em-7")]
   ...:         print(rank,team, wins, losses)
   ...:     
1  Counter Logic Gaming 10 1
2  Team EnVyUs 8 3
3  Enigma6 8 3
4  Renegades 6 5
5  Team Allegiance 5 6
6  Evil Geniuses 4 7
7  OpTic Gaming 2 9
8  Team Liquid 1 10
```

Comment: Let me test this answer before validating ! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries, test away;)

Comment: Wow, dude literally thanks so much. When I say I was staring at the screen trying to figure out what was going, it's not a joke! Thanks so much again! It'll be even better if you can explain the `iteration block`!

Comment: No prob, am away from the comp for a bit but I will break it down when I get back on later