# Can't use bytecode datas on get() function in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm having an issue with Beautiful Soup, when parsing a page with the `find_all()` and `get()` functions, like this:

```
req=Request("http://www.some_site.com/page/2",headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

page=urlopen(req).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')


for token in soup.find_all('a'):

    print(token.get('title'))
```

I get an error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 30: character maps to

The problem comes from this line:

```
print(token.get('title'))
```

I don't know what to do here, I could change the code of the get function in Beautiful source code or I could erase all the unicode datas in the webpage, but isn't there a solution only using beautiful soup ?

Thanks

Comment: regarding your second issue - there was this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38260853/bytes-object-has-no-attribute-find-all

Comment: @SergeyLebedev The solution provided in your link does not work, when calling page.find_all('a() I still have the first error I was talking about

Comment: Sorry I just edited, the problem comes from the get function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the `get` method but in the `print` fonction. BeautifulSoup correctly processes everything as Unicode, but to print the result you (may have to) convert the unicode string in bytes.

Depending on your system, common encodings are Latin1, cp1252 or utf8. Assuming utf8, you should use:

```
print(token.get('title').encode('utf8'))
```

Unfortunately, it will be harder for single byte charsets like latin1 or cp1252 because the unicode character [U+2019](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=2019) (right quotation mark: `’`) does not exist in either.

You will have to chose one of the codecs handling:

- strict (default): raise a UnicodeEncodeError
- replace: replace the offending character with a '?'
- ignore : just skip the offending character

My advice would be to first translate all characters that can be. For example the right quotation mark `u'\u2019'` could be replaced by the normal quote `'` or `'\x27'`. The problem is that I know no official list for those *simplification*. The best I can propose is to start with what is enough to process that page, and increase the translation tab with new characters with something like that:

```
try:
    txt = token.get('title').encode('latin1')
except UnicodeEncodeError as e:
    # store the error message that will be used to increase the translation map
    # e.object contains the offending character
    txt = token.get('title').encode('latin1', 'ignore')  # or 'replace'
print(txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests, bs4
req=requests.get("http://www.jazzadvice.com/page/2",headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
page=req.text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
for token in soup.find_all('a', title=True):

    print(token.get('title'))
```

out:

```
Login
Permanent Link to How to Play the Blues Like a Pro: A Lesson with Wynton Kelly
Permanent Link to The Talent Myth: Why Exceptional Musical Ability Is Within Your Reach
Permanent Link to The Beginner’s Guide to Jazz Articulation: Coltrane Techniques Demystified
Permanent Link to 4 Steps to Mastering the Solo Break: A Lesson With Clifford Brown
Permanent Link to How to Completely Change How You Think About Practicing: Words of Wisdom from Harold Mabern
Permanent Link to Killer Triadic & Pentatonic Concepts Made Easy: A Lesson With Kenny Garrett
Permanent Link to How Thinking Like a Writer Will Make You a Better Jazz Improvisor
Permanent Link to How to Learn Chord Changes Straight Off a Recording: A Handbook [Free Download]
Permanent Link to Why This Two-Step Approach to Jazz Language Will Take Your Improvising from Good to Great
Permanent Link to 2 Simple and Effective Practice Plans for Jazz Improvisation [Free Download]
October 10, 2011
April 7, 2011
April 20, 2011
January 26, 2014
November 24, 2010
April 13, 2014
June 22, 2011
November 20, 2011
March 20, 2012
April 14, 2010
June 15, 2010
April 10, 2013
April 29, 2011
December 8, 2010
June 3, 2010
December 17, 2010
April 18, 2010
December 22, 2010
February 18, 2011
June 9, 2011
May 27, 2010
July 16, 2010
January 7, 2011
November 9, 2010
July 7, 2010
May 17, 2010
May 18, 2010
February 3, 2011
January 19, 2011
November 12, 2010
```

Comment: I just edited, the problem comes from the get function

Comment: @HolyGraal post url

Comment: It does not work for the entire page, you just posted the begining of the output

Comment: @HolyGraal you problem is your code get an Error, now it works, if you want to add another question, update you question.